# problem deploy django to aws ec2 using nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, production

I want to connect my ip adress to a domain name. When I run in a browser "my.ip.adress" the server responds but when I try with "mydomain.com" it doesn't work. I have a 404 error. In my hosting platform I linked "my.ip.adress" to the domain name. I have wait 48 hours as it's recommended to link ip with domaine name.

I'm not sure of the configuration that I did. Maybe my env file ".env-prod" is not call and the pipes break

Could you help me

the folder representation:

```
env/
myblog/
    mysite/
        settings.py
        wsgi.py
        …
    scripts/
    static/
```

my env file : .env-prod

```
export DEBUG=off
export SECRET_KEY='mysecretkey'
export ALLOWED_HOSTS="['my.ip.adress', 'mydomain.com', 'www.mydomain.com']"
export DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:password@db.example.com:5432/production_db?sslmode=require
```

I have this /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

I have /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu 
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/myblog
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/env/bin/gunicorn \
--access-logfile - \
--workers 3 \
--bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
mysite.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I do

```
sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket
```

I have also /etc/nginx/sites-available/myblog
server {

```
    listen 80; server_name my.ip.adress; # could I have mydomain.com and www.mydomaine.com there ?
    root /home/ubuntu/myblog/;

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/myblog/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

then I do
sudo nginx -t
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myblog /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo systemctl restart nginx

In my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html; # is it important to conserve this line ?

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

 listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I use supervisor and this is my configuration. to install that
sudo apt-get install supervisor

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/myblog-gunicorn.conf

```
[program:myblog-gunicorn]
command = /home/ubuntu/env/bin/gunicorn mysite.wsgi:application
user = ubuntu
directory = /home/ubuntu/myblog
autostart = true
autorestart = true
```

then I do
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
sudo supervisorctl status

Comment: `In my hosting platform I linked "my.ip.adress" to the domain name`: How did you do that? You need to create an `A` (and possibly `AAAA`) record on a DNS server.

Comment: I have a A ftp and a A @ associate to the "my.ip.adress". To add a AAAA do I need to link to have @ as follow : type: AAAA, name: @, content: "my.ip.adress", ttl: 14400

Comment: What does `dig a mydomain.com +short` say? Is your actual domain name confidential?

Comment: I have mydomain.com. and the next line is the good ip adress. Actually it's an fr domaine (but that changes nothing )

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you only need to delete the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file